# c# - using : bad practice to use?

Tags: c#, .net, using

I have read more that year ago that there are a few bad practice to use

```
using (some code) {

}
```

. Could someone explain me all these bad practice?
Thanks.

Comment: It's a bad practice to ask this w/o any references.

Comment: You'll need to provide some reference as to where this is stated. It is generally seen strongly as a good practice when dealing with types implementing `IDisposable`.

Comment: I thought it was good practice to use 'using' wherever possible (if you want to dispose of the object after using it)

Comment: Move the opening brace down a line?

Comment: More info needed. Generally it is a good practice.

Comment: The question has been closed to early IMO. Using might not be suitable in some case. It does not mean releasing resources is bad, it means it has to be done another way. For example, have a look on this post about using in WCF Client: http://omaralzabir.com/do-not-use-using-in-wcf-client/

Comment: @Laurent: good reference but still a very bad question. OP should have researched a little, not based a question on something half remembered.

Comment: Question is not formed well, however - it touches on an often overlooked problem with using 'using' in multithreaded scenarios (http://www.nujk.com/is-c-39-s-using-statement-abort-safe).

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think it's a bad practice? It can be a very good (or best) practice since the object will be disposed immediately after the using block.

Answer (score 2):

No - it isn't bad practice at all - in many cases it is extremely good practice.

Using the "using" approach, you can write code knowing that `IDisposable` types are automatically disposed of as soon as they go out of scope, meaning you don't need to manually call `Dispose()` at every exit point to your code.

Having said that, you can certainly come up with some bad usages of `Dispose()`, but it is not intrinsically bad, and more often than not is good.